# What is the meaning of "It's a Start"?

Tags: meaning

Peter doubted by Regina that he might killed Charles and Scobie.

> Regina: Whoever's left alive at the end will pretty much have sewn up
>   the nomination, don't you think?
>
> Peter: What are you trying to say, that I might have  killed Charles
>   and Scobie? What do I have to do to satisfy  you? Become the next
>   victim?
>
> Regina: **It’s a start**, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess = it could mean *It's **only** a start, there will be more corpses to come.*

Answer (score 0):

Regina suggested that Peter had a reason to kill Charles and Scobie.

Peter asked if Regina believes that Peter killed Charles and Scobie. Peter also asked how he can prove that he is not the killer.  Peter asked if he could prove he is not the killer by getting killed.

When Regina says "It's a start" she is saying to Peter:
   If you were killed, then it be the first of many steps toward making be believe that you are not the killer.

The conversation is sardonic. Peter does not really plan to die to prove he is not the killer.  Regina does really mean that she would still think Peter is the killer even if he were killed.